# Listboxes hierarchy

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have 3 embedded listboxes for entities: group, item, subitem.

```
<ListBox Name="GroupItemsListBox"
         ItemSource="{Binding EntityGroups"}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsListBox"
                          ItemSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl Name="SubItemsListBox"
                                      ItemSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name} />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate />
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Also there is a case when last listbox is empty. 
I want to handle SelectedItem from the lowest existing ItemControl. So i will be able to manage when the most specific object is selected.

For example when i click on ItemGroup[1].Items[0].SubItem[2] i want to get this element, but not ItemGroup[1] or ItemGroup[1].Items[0].

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LongListSelector` instead. This supports grouping in a much nicer way.